# Using a linear fit to create p-values from the response values of a generalized boosted regression model

Tags: r, regression, lm, boosting

I am creating a boosted regression model in R using

- a binary target,
- several string variables including missing values (as.factor) and
- several continuous numerical variables with missing values imputed as a large negative number.

My problem is that the response values of the resulting model cannot be interpreted as p-values:

```
> vFormulaStr <- paste(target,'~',paste(variables,collapse='+'))
>
> modelGBM <- gbm(as.formula(vFormulaStr),data=mydata,distribution="gaussian",n.trees=100,interaction.depth=length(variables),n.minobsinnode = 20)
>  
> resp = predict(modelGBM,type="response",single.tree=FALSE,n.trees=100)
> range(resp)
[1] 1.132390 1.199362
```

because the response values fall in the range [1.132390,1.199362] and not in the range [0,1].

In order to interpret these response values as p-values, I have fitted linearly the response values into the target values:

```
> y = modelGBM$data$y; y <- as.numeric(levels(y))[y]
> p <- predict(lm(y ~ resp),type="response")
> range(p)
[1] 0.03179395 0.86170170
```

As a result, the resulting fit seems to be as expected: average `target` value corresponds to the respective `p` value. However, I am wondering two questions:

1. Whether such a linear conversion is the most suitable conversion to produce p-values from the response values of a GBM model?
2. Whether there is a more suitable method to convert the GBM response values into p-values?

Comment: Soft max would be a solution, but given you are doing a binary classification, why are you doing a regression tree ?  Why not an ordinary tree ?

Comment: The main question is that **is the unavailability of p-value property of the trees** and, therefore, one should fit a smooth function in order to obtain p-value from the response value of model.

Comment: I am trying different kind of tree models which would result into a p-value when applied into another data sample from similar conditions. Given that I have quite many variables, an ordinary tree could also give relatively smooth piecewise discretized p-value vs. average target curve. I will certainly try also that one.

Comment: You might try bootstrapping to get p-values.  Given a complete lack of knowledge about the actual distribution, boostrapping is arguably the more statistically justified procedure to find confidence intervals.